# Make jquery selector dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a jquery selector dynamically by concatenating a function input `id` onto the str "a"

```
eval(0);

function eval(id) {
    var a = id + 1;
    a = "a" + a;
    $("input[name='a']").val(response.success);
}
```

How can I make this not just search for the input with name `a`, but for input with the name of variable `a`

Comment: Erm... `$("input[name='"+a+"']")`???

Comment: Simple as $("input[name='"+ a +"']").

Comment: eval is a bad name since there is `window.eval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the variable inside the selector:

```
$("input[name='" + a + "']").val(response.success);
```

Comment: Yeah it was the quote notation that I was having trouble with.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is a key word in javascript. Avoid any using that name .

Here `a` need to passed as variable instead of string

```
evaluate(0);
function evaluate(id) {
    var a = id + 1;
    a = "a" + a;
    $("input[name='"+a+"']").val(response.success);
}
```

Comment: Yeah copying and pasting would have been a pain because there's a lot of code around the relevant code so i just freehanded it and must've have eval() on my mind.  The function names are different in my code.  Good point though.